# How do I resize an image so that the longest size is shorter or equal to an amount?

Tags: imagemagick

The following resizes JPEG files so that the width becomes at most 1000px:

```
mogrify -resize "1000>" *.jpg
```

How do I resize the JPEGs so that the *longer* side is less than 1000px?

---

<sub>See also: [documentation on `-resize` argument format](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry).</sub>

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It should keep the aspect ratio / image proportions when using a geometry string with ">", so you can just do:

```
mogrify -resize "1000x1000>" *.jpg
```

So you're explicitly limiting the image to being, at most, 1000x1000 pixels, and keeping the current aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Ah, I see. Does this mean that the example I gave only resizes in one dimension?

Comment: I honestly don't remember what specifying a single dimension does. Check the docs for the geometry strings if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
find . -type f -exec convert {} -resize "1000>" {} \;
```

this might also be:

```
find ./*.jpg -exec convert {} -resize "1000>" {} \;
```