# Resize big images so the shortest size is at most x pixels keeping ratio?

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick, mogrify

I want to convert images using `mogrify`, so the smaller size is 768 keeping the aspect ratio, but without touching images which have the smallest size shorter than 768 pixels. For example:

```
1536x2000 -> 768x1000
3072x4000 -> 768x1000
600x900 -> 600x900
```

How can I do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694823/how-do-i-resize-an-image-so-that-the-longest-size-is-shorter-or-equal-to-an-amou) but it seems different from what I want

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Linux

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution by myself:

```
 mogrify -resize 768x768^\> *.jpg
```

Am I wrong?